# Can't access internet through network share

Tags: macos, wifi, internet-sharing

I have an MBP with the latest OSX connected to the internet through ethernet. I've created a wi-fi network with the same name as the laptop and set the WPA2 password. I then enabled internet sharing in System Preferences.

I then booted another laptop also running the latest OSX and tried to connect to that network. The network was visible and I made sure I could see the password but my other laptop was unable to connect to the wi-fi network. Both machines are on the same desk.

How can I debug this? Console seems to show nothing relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are **sharing internet from Ethernet** to others computers **using WiFi/Airport**

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I have.

Comment: Could you check if you are getting IP ?
If you are getting one, add router IP as DNS too, See if it helps